# Flex: Multiple modules conflict

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, module, blazeds

I have multiple modules within a `Flex` application. All of them have web service calls to remote applications. **Module 1** is a search engine that requires a long running web service call, and while waiting, I loaded the **Module 2**. The parameters that should be loaded in **Module 2** could not be loaded as **Module 1**'s web service have not returned yet.

All these modules are running remote web service calls through `BlazeDS`.
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Wait in module 2 for the data loaded via modules 1.

Comment: i require both of the modules to fire asynchronously without affecting each other. but there is a waiting queue within them and the main application holding it, is there any solution?

Comment: Yes, if you structure your application according to the MVC Pattern, you could precisely control each view. Frameworks like robot legs use an event bus, to let view controllers communicate with each other. So when the service, which is invoked in Module 1 is ready, it would use the bus to notify interested peers. I'd recommend kicking any logic out of the modules. If there are service implementations specific to the module, grab the instances out and let a supervising controller handle the data management - perhaps in a queue or the queue you already have.

Comment: i think it is abit hard or too late to bring all logic out of both modules. as both modules are developed by different development teams, we are both using cairngorm framework, not sure is there something that requires to be configured to prevent both from queueing each other